# Help identify large white wheels

Tags: part-identification, wheel, space

Have lots of mixed pieces that we bought second hand. We have come across very large white plastic solid wheels, resembles sand buggy wheels, but think they must be space related as they are white. Pieces could be from early 80s and forward.I might be wrong to think they are wheels but they came assembled like this so always thought they were. Love to find out which set they might have come from so we can build something awesome.[image].

Answer (score 4):

What you have there is a [6118 Wheel Hard Plastic Small (22mm D. x 24mm)](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=6118), and this wheel is pretty common, it features in [39 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6118&in=S), but luckily for you only in 4 sets in the color White. These sets are:

- [1704-1  Ice Planet Satellite Plow](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=1704-1) - this set has 6 of these wheels.

[image]

- [6983-1 Ice Station Odyssey](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=6983-1) - this set has 10 of these wheels.

[image]

- [6814-1 Ice Tunnelator](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=6814-1) - this set has 4 of these wheels.

[image]

- [6898-1 Ice-Sat V](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=6898-1) - this set has 8 of these wheels.

[image]

If you count the number of wheels you have, you should be able to deduce which set they came from as each set has a different number of wheels.